# Lubuntu 16.04 stuck at splash screen

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, plymouth, persistence, mkusb

I have installed Lubuntu on an external drive with the tool mkusb. All worked well for months until yesterday, I am stuck at the splash screen and I dont know how I can solve this problem.

I have selected "persistent live" if that makes a difference, my system is a persistent one.

I can however load into recovery mode, this is the mode which I am in right now.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)**  Have you tried loading a previous kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Your Lubuntu system boots into recovery mode.

- Does it boot into 'Try Lubuntu without installing' alias 'Live Only' without persistence? If that is the case, I think the partition for persistence and its file system is damaged. You can try to repair it, when ***not*** booted with persistence,

  ```
  sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdx5
  ```

  where x is the drive letter, found via for example

  ```
  sudo lsblk -f`
  ```
- Otherwise, if it does not help or work to repair the file system, I suggest that you

  - recover the personal files (documents, pictures etc) that are important
  - keep the directory

    ```
    /media/lubuntu/casper-rw/upper/home
    ```

    but remove all other files and directories from

    ```
    /media/lubuntu/casper-rw/upper
    ```

    Your personal files and tweaks should be preserved, but you must reinstall the programs that you have installed.
  - or if necessary, remove all files and directories from the casper-rw partition and restart persistence by installing programs and tweaking the system.
- The partition that stores persistent overlay data is easily damaged, particularly if you remove the pendrive before it is unmounted, so please use the backup and restore tools described at

  [mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data)

Comment: Hey man it worked. I am back on my machine. thanks a lot man.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :-)